# what's the right design pattern for complicate decision making system

Tags: java, architecture, design-patterns

I am working on the design of a decision making system that invokes complicate logic, potentially I will need to use a lot of nested if/else statements,

I want to see if is there a better design patter than can help me to simplify the structure of the system and provide a certain extensibility for future improvement.

The problem of the project can be simpified as:

We are now need to making a decision for a request, which has 3 type of properties, and potentially more. They are PricePolicy (Contract/WholeSale/Retail/Discount), RequestType (Buy/Sell) and ProductType (Fashion/Household/Toys).

Each decision making is based on all the 3 properties of the request, because the type of price policy may change in the future, and more properties will be added to the decision making process.

So I am trying to avoid the making a large switch statement, which is ugly and deficult for future extensions. Such as:

```
switch(ProductType) {
 case Fashion:
   switch(PricePolicy) {
     case Contract:
       if(Request == Buy) {
         // making a decision.
       } else {
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Please share you idea and suggestions Thank you.

Cheers,
Bob

Comment: For this kind of systems Prolog is your friend

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you want a Rete rules engine.  Try Drools.

Or a data-driven decision table.

If you want a class solution, think polymorphism.  Replace all those if/then/else cases with classes like Strategy or Visitor.

The key is stable interfaces.  If you can keep that stable, and change the implementations underneath, you've got it.

Comment: I do like polymorphism, but it increase the vertical dependency, so if I want to change the method signature of the base class. All the inherit classes have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Use a n-dimensional array, and lookup/query/modify your decisions that way.

Comment: That's a clever way to avoid the switch statement, but from design point of view, I believe we are still using the same switch statement, just smarter. 

and we have to hardcode the action into the index. Do you think so...

Answer (score 0):

As ziplin suggested, I would consider a 3d array if there is a decision for each combination (ie. not a 'sparse' distribution of decisions - I think that's the correct term).  This would require that you are able to encapsulate the decision logic in an expression which can be stored within the array.  With a sparse distribution, an adjacency list could be used in a similar fashion.